# Nuclear physics explained by QCD

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, binding-energy, strong-force, elements

I have been studying Particle & nuclear physics and I know that nuclear physics should normally be explained by particle physics. Specifically, I would like to ask if there is any theoretical research going on (after 1983, I found an article from that year), that is trying to explain nuclear binding energy using the QCD theory (by using strong nuclear force to explain mathematically how the binding energy derives- if we get the same numbers using the liquid drop model and this QCD calculations etc...). If there is, would you please give me a short description of the theory?

Comment: Nuclear forces involve [meson exchange](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nuclear_Forces).

Comment: Chiral perturbation theory might be your best bet.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the meson theory and chiral EFT is what I need. In the begining, I was thinking the whole phenomenon as a quark tunneling from nucleon to nucleon, but now it makes sense. Thank you for the answers again!